# Fortran tips in large modules

Tags: module, fortran, subroutine

I have a module that consists of many small subroutines and one main subroutine, which is the only one that is public. The rest of the subroutines are private and called by the main subroutine or within them. The main subroutine has to take all the necessary arguments to perform its work, but often when it delivers a task to a private subroutine, it has to pass again some of the arguments. I would like to avoid this when dealing with arrays. With scalar numbers I can simply define a module wide variable and assign it the corresponding value in the main subroutine:

```
module test
    integer, private :: m, n
    private :: foo
    public :: main

contains

    subroutine main(matrixA, m0, n0)
        integer, intent(in) :: m0, n0
        real, intent(inout) :: matrixA(m0,n0)

        !assign values to module variables m & n
        m = m0
        n = n0
        ...

        !no need to pass m0 & n0
        call foo(matrixA)
    end subroutine

    subroutine foo(matrixA)
        real, intent(inout) :: matrixA(m,n)

        ...

    end subroutine
end module
```

I would like to also not need to pass `matrixA` at all. What is the best way to do this? By best, I mean giving the best performance.

Comment: Did you profile the code to claim the argument passing is the bottle-neck? If you find assumed shape arrays too slow inside looos try the `contiguous` attribute.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely slower, like 30 secs for explicit shape, and a little more than 40 secs for assumed shape. Also, I tried using module wide pointers, so that in main I would just assign these pointers to the matrices, and let the rest of the subroutines use these pointers. It was even slower (48 secs). I will try `contiguous`, does it work in Fortran 90?
This [link](http://wiki.seas.harvard.edu/geos-chem/index.php/Passing_array_arguments_efficiently_in_GEOS-Chem) has more about assumed shape performance.

Comment: `contiguous` is Fortran 2008. Fortran 90 is essentially dead, don't care about anything earlier than 95.

Comment: Could you perhaps show the main program parts around the call to `main` and the declarations?

Comment: Code is very long but here is it: https://github.com/mikolchon/cfd/blob/master/smoothing.f90

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the "best" way, but there are some things to say.  And now the question has been edited to point "best" in the direction of performance I'll add something else.

The question appears to be made under the premise that arrays cannot be module variables.  They can be, even allocatable/pointer (deferred-shape) ones.

In the examples that follow I'll make the assumption that the array dummy argument in `main` will be assumed-shape.  This is just to make things simpler in the form; changing to explicit-shape is a simple extension.

First, just like we set `m` and `n` in the question, we can set a module array variable.

```
module test
  private     ! Have this as default
  public main ! But we do want a way in

  integer m, n
  real, allocatable :: matrixA(:,:)

contains
  ! In this subroutine we're making an assumption that the person asking isn't
  ! wholly correct in not wanting to assume shape.  But we can change that if
  ! required.  It's just a more natural thing if one can.
  subroutine main(matrix)               ! Note, not passing m, n
    real, intent(inout) :: matrix(:,:)  ! It's assumed shape

    m = SIZE(matrix,1)
    n = SIZE(matrix,2)

    matrixA = matrix  ! Copy in to the module's matrixA

    call foo()
    ! .... etc.

    matrix = matrixA  ! Copy back out to the dummy

  end subroutine main

  subroutine foo
    ! Here we have access to the module's matrixA
    ! And we do our stuff
  end subroutine foo

end module test
```

Note the use of the assumed-shape dummy argument and the discussion above.  To avoid copying in this example, one could think about whether using a pointer is a suitable thing.

With the copy, that's not going to be good performance (assuming the array is biiig).  So:

```
module test
  implicit none
  private
  integer m, n ! If we want these we'll have to set them somehow
  real, allocatable, public :: matrixA(:,:)

  public main

contains

  subroutine main()
    ! Stuff with matrixA host-associated
  end subroutine main

end module test

program hello
  use test, only : matrixA, main
  implicit none

  matrixA = ...  ! Set this: it's matrixA from the module
  call main
end program hello
```

As we care about "performance" rather than "encapsulation" that seems like a reasonable thing.  However, having encapsulation, performance and reduced-argument passing, we could consider, rather than using a module variable for `matrixA`, having the work subroutines internal to `main`.

```
 module test
 contains
   subroutine main(matrixA)
     real, intent(inout)  :: matrixA(:,:)

     call foo

    contains
     subroutine foo
       ! Here we have access to matrixA under host association
     end subroutine foo
   end subroutine main
 end module test
```

In many circumstances I prefer this last, but wouldn't say it's best, or even preferred under all circumstances.  Note, in particular, that if `foo` already has an internal subprogram we'll start to wonder about life.

I feel the first is rather extreme just to avoid passing as an argument.

Comment: Not worth editing into the question, but: deferred shape in general for a module variable.  One may think that `matrixA` in the module could have the `pointer` attribute.

Comment: Second choice is definitely better since assumed shape are known to be less efficient. If the subroutine is called many times, the performance loss is noticeable. Also, it is better if I don't need to copy the entire matrix up to the module every time I call main. Edit: sorry but with the second approach I will still need to pass explicitly some arguments within the "subsubroutines".

Comment: Passing bounds (which is quite reasonable) is a simple extension to my examples.  As it is, I'll keep the code as is, as that's clearer in elucidation (I think).  Note that if `m0` and `n0` are passed in the internal case those will also be available by host association.  Indeed, anything defined in/passed to/associated in `main` will be available to any internal subprogram (unless a competing name is used there).  Does this latter answer your comment-edit?